# permission doesnt show up in my permissions page

Tags: drupal, permissions, drupal-7, hook, drupal-modules

I have installed Drupal 7.34 in my computer and created a module named "mymodule". I already created successfully the file mymodule.info and mymodule.module. Below are their following contents:

[mymodule.info]

```
; $Id$
name = mymodule
description = Alyssa Gono's first module.
core = 7.x
package = Example
```

[mymodule.module]

```
<?php
// $Id$

/**
 * @file
 * Main module file for  mymodule Module.
*/
/**
 * Implementation of hook_permission().
 *
 * This function takes 0 arguments, and returns an array of permissions defined by our module.   Our permissions are automatically made avilable 
 * under admin/user/permissions.
 */

function mymodule_permission() {
    return array(
        'administer mymodule' => array(
        'title' => t('Administer mymodule'),
        'description' => t('Perform administration tasks for mymodule.'),
    ),
  );
}
```

But when I navigate to Permissions Page, to find out if my hook permissions was implemented successfully, the permission I made seems not to show up. where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks fine. Maybe it is a cache issue. Try clearing the cache from `?q=admin/config/development/performance` and see if the permission is shown.